# Microsoft Search Server 2008 File Links not clickable

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, internet-explorer

I have installed Microsoft Search Server 2008 on a Win23k Server, and have configured a content source to crawl a shared file system. The content source is configured as "file://server-name/directory-name". The crawling and indexing is working fine, and search results are displaying as required on the results page.

The trouble is that the file links are not click-able, which of course makes the search results completely useless. Search server is clearly hyperlinking them but clicking on the hyperlinks in the browsers does nothing except make a clicking noise.

So an example of a hyperlink created in the browser by Search Server is

```
<a href="file://server-name/directory-name/file-name.doc" id="CSR_2"  
title="file://server-name/directory-name/file-name.doc">file-name.doc</a>
```

Most of users use either chrome or internet explorer to access the search site. How can I configure search server so that users can click to open files in their browsers?

EDIT

Turns out that this is not a problem when the site is in the trusted Intranet Zone. I wrote a VBA script which the users have on their desktops which configures Internet Explorer to have the site in trusted Intranet Zone, and then launches Internet Explorer. The users treat this script as a link to the site. This way I can be sure that they use Internet Explorer to do their searches and not Chrome or Firefox.

```
On Error Resume Next

Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."
Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & strComputer & _
    "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\ESCDomains\YOURSITE.COM"
objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath
strValueName = "http"
dwValue = 2
objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue

 Dim iExplorer
 Set iExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 iExplorer.navigate "http://YOURSITE.COM"
 iExplorer.Visible = True
```